# Comment exprimer de quatre manières différentes la relation entre ces deux evenements?

Tags: expressions

◘ **Exprimer la relation cause/conséquence**

**Exercice 6 :** Comment exprimer de quatre manières différentes la relation entre ces deux événements:

> En 1914, Jaurès milite contre la guerre. Il est assassiné.

Ma solution:

1. Jaurès a été assassiné car il a milité contre la guerre en 1914
2. Jaurès milite contre la guerre en 1914, c'est pourquoi il a été assassiné

Il me reste deux, aidez-moi s'il vous plait.

Comment: Quel est le but de la question ? Il doit y avoir un contexte... Si c'est la question d'un examen, soit il nous faut plus de précisions sur le thème abordé, soit on ne peut rien faire. Sinon, si c'est une demande personnelle, j'ai du mal à comprendre pourquoi "4 manières"... La question devrait plutôt porter sur ce que vous avez du mal à comprendre. Pouvez vous préciser ?

Comment: c un exercice @Random, (il faut exprimer la relation cause/conséquence

Comment: Dans ce cas, qu'avez vous trouvé pour le moment ?

Comment: Jaurès a été assassiné car il a milité contre la guerre. @Random

Comment: Il s'agit d'un exercice, il doit y avoir eu un cours avec les différentes manières d'exprimer la cause/conséquence ? Je pense qu'il serait judicieux d'en donner quelques uns (que je suppose être des tournures de phrases plus qu'autre choses) afin qu'on puisse t'aider à les adapter, voir que tu essayes de les appliquer, et on t'indiquera pourquoi elles sont bonnes ou mauvaises...

Comment: -1 & vote de fermeture : Il faudrait d'abord que vous fournissiez les solutions que vous avez trouvées pour qu'elles puissent être corrigées ou validées. S'il y a exercice, c'est qu'il y a eu cours auparavant... Ce n'est pas en faisant réfléchir les autres à votre place que vous pourrez progresser en français :)

Comment: Ce site : http://www.francaisfacile.com/correspondants/google-results.php?q=CAUSE vous tapez *cause*, il ne reste plus qu'à lire :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu peux aussi dire:

> En 1914, Jaurès milite contre la guerre, il sera ensuite assassiné
>
> Jaurès est assassiné en 1914 car il milite contre la guerre
>
> En 1914, Jaurès milite contre la guerre et est assassiné